# When a GoPro is recording, how can I see whether it is recording a regular video or a timelapse?

Tags: video-recording, time-lapse, gopro

I use a GoPro 10. When it is recording, how can I see whether it is recording a regular video or a timelapse?

Answer (score 0):

Reddit user [All-Sorts-of-Stuff](https://www.reddit.com/user/All-Sorts-of-Stuff) [mentioned](https://redd.it/10maztg) that one can look at the red timer to see whether it is recording a regular video or a timelapse:

> While the camera is recording, there will be a red timer showing the footage duration on the rear screen. If that timer is ticking upwards slowly - eg., it takes a full minute for each "second" of the timer to increase - then the camera is recording a timelapse. If that timer is ticking upwards in real time, it's recording a video